# Sum lists of variable lengths element-wise

Tags: python

If I have a list of lists, and each nested list contains numbers, how can I add all of these lists element-wise into a single array?

i.e.

```
listOne = [1, 2, 3]
listTwo = [4, 5, 6]
listThree = [7, 8, 9, 10]
allLists = [listOne, listTwo, listThree]

total = add(allLists)
print total
```

output should be `[12, 15, 18, 10]`

Comment: Your second index of the sum should be 15, not 14.

Comment: Minor: `all` is the name of a very useful built-in, and so not a good name for a variable.

Comment: Could someone fill me in on what is actually being summed up here to create the output?

Comment: @timgeb, `1 + 4 + 7 = 12`, `2 + 5 + 8 = 15`, `3 + 6 + 9 = 18`, `0 + 0 + 10 = 10`

Comment: @mhlester ah, thanks. I thought of this at first but at that time there was a math error in the post so values did not add up properly :)

Comment: @Apollo, that's my son's name :)

Comment: @mhlester good choice :D it's a beautiful name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to remap rows/columns (like `zip` but to the longest element rather than shortest), filling shorter items 0

```
from itertools import izip_longest
total = [sum(x) for x in izip_longest(*allLists, fillvalue=0)]
```

Outputs:

```
[12, 15, 18, 10]
```

Also for your edification, the intermediate output of the zip_longest is:

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (0, 0, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a nice opportunity to practice list comprehensions ;)

```
maxlen = max(len(lst) for lst in allLists) # find length of longest list
sumlist = [sum([lst[i] if i<len(lst) else 0 for lst in allLists]) for i in range(maxlen)]
```

gives `sumlist`

[12, 15, 18, 10]